# jQuery Plugin not returning results from JSON return of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, autosuggest

So I'm using this jQuery plugin:
[jSuggest](http://pastebin.com/7L60d5e2)
Which is based on this plugin: [autoSuggest](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

Here's a jsFiddle with the (working) demo of jSuggest: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yLnyP/1/)

This is the code I am using to instantiate the plugin on my page:

```
<form id="add" action="components/AddItem.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="center clear">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Basic Information</legend>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                ...[snip]...
        </form>
```

.

```
$( '#name' ).jSuggest({
                        source: "components/suggItem.php",
                        selectedItemProp: "name",
                        seekVal: "name",
                        selectionLimit: 1,
                        uniqID: "item",
                        keyDelay: 100,
                        newText: "You must click outside the text box to add a new item."
                        });
```

This is the string that returns from `"components/suggItem.php"` when I type "ch" into the textbox:

`[ {"value":"1","name":"Cheeseburger"},{"value":"3","name":"Fish Sandwich"} ]`

(That's `Content-type: application/json` and I'm getting it from FireBug)

However, the only thing I **ever** get in the dropdown is `"No Results Found"`.  Can anyone find a bug in my code?

I have also tried:

```
$( '#name' ).jSuggest({
                        source: "components/suggItem.php",
                        seekVal: "name",
                        });
```

and various combinations of `"value"` and `"name"`.

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.  Any help?

Comment: What made you choose that particular plugin? I don't see how its ajax handling code can possibly work properly.

Comment: @Pointy I liked Drew Wilson's plugin, and this one fixed a lot of the bugs in his.  I'm open to better suggestions...  Which AJAX part do you mean?  It uses jQuery's getJSON, so I would think it's pretty solid.

Comment: It *misuses* getJSON - the code you posted seems to assume that the results of getJSON will be available immediately, which is false. That code you posted also looks a lot different than the code available from what appears to be the plugin home page, http://scottreeddesign.com/project/jsuggest

Comment: That's the "official" jSuggest plugin.  The plugin I'm using is based on the autoSuggest plugin by Drew Wilson, and was only named jSuggest because, I assume, the author wasn't aware of the others.  Here's where I got the link from [Drew's Support Site](https://drew.tenderapp.com/discussions/autosuggest/193-jsuggest-autosuggest-but-with-some-features-added).  UPDATE: @Pointy It appears you're right about the JSON issue.  Could you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: @Pointy, if you make your answer ("JSON is broken") an answer, I'll give it to you.  I've switched to the jquery.ui autosuggest.  Less pretty, but I understand it completely.

Comment: @rockerest I've added an answer. It's a little weird that the plugin would have such problems; it's got to be the case that the author hasn't really tried it (much) with a real site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That plugin may have its advantages, but the author appears to be suffering from a significant misunderstanding of the way AJAX works.  This code here:

```
        // If the data is a URL, retrieve the results from it. Else, the data is an object, retrieve the results directly from the source.
        if (dType === 'string'){

          // Set up the limit of the query.
          var limit = qLimit ? "&limit="+encodeURIComponent(qLimit) : '';

          // Build the query and retrieve the response in JSON format.
          $.getJSON(theData+"?"+opts.queryParam+"="+encodeURIComponent(string)+limit+opts.extraParams, function(rData){ theData = rData; });

        }

        // Call the custom retrieveComplete function.
        theData = opts.retrieveComplete.call(this, theData);
```

*appears* to me to assume that the "getJSON" call will invoke the function argument synchronously, such that the variable "theData" will be updated before that last (shown) line of code is executed. That's just not going to be true, however, and "theData" is the key object that drives the whole autocomplete mechanism.

The original code (for the "autoSuggest" plugin that seems to be the progenitor of "jSuggest") looks critically different around that code, and it correctly defers the interpretation of the JSON data returned from the ajax call to the handler routine.

Comment: After a little testing, trying to get the results from a JSON url didn't work with this plugin, while using a hard-coded dataset seemed fine.  Since a JSON url worked perfectly with the "progenitor" plugin, I think this is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $( '#name' ).jSuggest({source: "components/suggItem.php",                              
selectedItemProp: "name", 
seekVal: "name"  
 });
```

All these three properties are required for it to work. Verify that it works by passing the source property an array directly rather than the url, and once that is going try the url.

Comment: So it looks like the JSON handler in the plugin isn't working, because I've always included those three properties and your suggestion to try the array first resulted in success.  Any ideas about why the JSON isn't working?